# Sticky XHR cache with angular 1.3.11 and Safari 9

Tags: angularjs, safari

I think I know how Safari is so "fast" they just cache the heck out of everything. What I am seeing is, two requests to the same url (even though they have different media types) are being returned with the same data. I have no cache headers in the $httpProvider but it still doesn't work. Anyone hit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure you have two options here.

1. Cache bust every request with a parameter, such as a timestamp
2. Add appropriate cache headers to your request to force Safari to respect the request

   ```
   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
   Pragma: no-cache
   Expires: 0
   ```

Comment: It's absurd how sticky this is. I am developing an interceptor to do this only to my /rest requests.

Comment: Are you certain that you aren't caching via angular somewhere in your base $http implementation?  Is the request even being served up by safari as cached content?

Comment: I have never used the http cache ever.

Comment: Then one of the two suggestions I've given should fix the problem for you.

Comment: This is via $resource, but what I see is, in ONLY SAFARI - two request to the same url the second request never goes out but is returned immediately with the content from the first. The second request has a diff media type, and in every other browser fires twice. In Safari, it only goes out once.

Comment: The easiest solution is a query string parameter with the timestamp for the second request.  That would force safari to requery the server.

Comment: yes it does work, with a global $httpInterceptor, it's a huge app I can't predict which is the second.

Comment: @httpete You'll have to forgive me, but based on what you've posted I'm going off of just assumptions.  It seems to me that if you query-param the calls for JUST that URL you'll be fine.